# How to use ASP Controls inside a jQuery Dialog box ?

Tags: asp.net, listbox, postback, jquery-dialog, autopostback

I have a div which is working as a `jQuery Dialog` box. Inside that I have two `asp:ListBoxes` and a `asp:button`. I want to select an Item from the `ListBox1` and when clicking the `button` that Item should move to `ListBox2`. But when I clicking on the button `Postback` occurs and closes the jQuery Dialog.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Bad idea, you do NOT want to do a postback here. Moving things on the client side should not result in a postback. Instead, have a Web API that you can use AJAX to communicate with in the background if you need server side interaction.

Comment: @mason I used UpdatePanel and it worked. Thank you for the helping :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you, but beware that UpdatePanel is notorious for causing hard to debug problems. You're much better off working with the established way of having server side interaction via AJAX than using heavy controls like UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an `UpdatePanel` "inside" the Dialog Box and put `asp:ListBoxes` inside `UpdatePanel` so you prevent page from doing refresh and also Dialog Box doesn't disappear because it's outside of UpdatePanel.